# using custom Id column mapping with Searchable plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, searchable

I have a Domain class with a custom Id mapping

```
...
...
String ensemblGeneId
    String ensemblTranscriptId
    String ensemblProteinId
    String proteinSequence
    String topologySequence
    String topologyRatio
    String description
    String geneName

    ..       
    ..                                     
    ..

    static mapping = {
        proteinSequence type:'text'
        topologySequence type:'text'    
        description type:'text' 
        id name:'ensemblProteinId', generator:'assigned'    
    }
```

i have a problem making this work with the searchable plugin

i add the following to the class

```
    static searchable = {
    id name:'ensemblProteinId'
    except = ['topologySequence','proteinSequence']

}
```

I receive the following error after the data insert is completed

```
2010-07-06 13:35:08,091 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Id with path [$/Protein/id] for alias [Protein] not found
org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException: Id with path [$/Protein/id] for alias [Protein] not found
```

it seems like it still tries to find a column named id instead of a column named ensemblProteinId.

is the searchable plugin supposed to work with custom id columns, if so what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There does appear to be an issue with custom domain ids and the searchable plugin. As a work around you can map the class using the compass annotations documented here:

http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Mapping+-+Compass+annotations

and here:

http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.1.4/reference/html/core-osem.html

So your class looks something like:

```
import org.compass.annotations.*
@Searchable(alias='Test')
...
class Test {
    @SearchableId
    String sampleId

    @SearchableProperty
    String sampleValue

    static mapping = {
        id name:'sampleId', generator: 'assigned'
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd also enable the debugging in your config.groovy by adding the lines

```
 debug  'grails.app',
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.searchable'
```

to your log4j configuration block(you may need to remove the 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins' line from the error block!)
This will let you see the compass mappings the plugin is producing.

Jim.